# Bash Completion hangs all inputs

Tags: bash, arch-linux, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

When I try to bash complete in terminal my computer stops responding to inputs, although the mouse can still be moved.  After a few seconds it picks back up and everything continues normally.

I'm running on:

- arch
- xorg
- gnome-shell
- gnome-terminal

Upon using `set -x`, I've found that it hangs at this particular command:

```
+ COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '$*' -- "$cur"))
```

From what I understand `compgen` is the backbone of bash completion.
Can anyone explain to me why this may be happening, or what I can do to avoid the freezing?

Comment: Is the tab-completion successful after it stops hanging?

Comment: yeah it does, shows a bunch of if/for statements after the `compgen`command which finish immediately.

Comment: depending on which command you are completing, it could be doing all kinds of things, even network requests.  Is it related to any specific command?  You might try running strace to see if it forked out to some other process.

Comment: OK, since I was lucky enough to be working on a fresh install, I re-partitioned my hard drive and added a swap partition.  This fixed all of the problems I was having and things are running great now.

Comment: Same thing here. arch too. bash 4.4.12(1). always had swap on. *Edit: happened after a upgrade, and resolved itself. I think something was generating whatever auto completion list it uses?